# Using Picker View - concept of setter, getter confusion

Tags: ios, uipickerview, setter, getter

Alright, here's my code for a simple PickerView and it's working too.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property NSArray *moods;
@end

@implementation ViewController


-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [[self moods] count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.moods[row];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.moods = @[@"I" , @"Love", @"Stack", @"Overflow", @"Great!"];
}
```

My question is about the confusing behaviour about the setter and getter method using properties. To further clarify, I don't know why the .(dot) notation of setter method works and the bracket style doesn't.

For example, under this method

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.moods[row];
}
```

If I type it in as

```
return [self moods[row]];
```

That doesn't work. Why? It says missing identifier and on further adding it too like this

```
return [self moods[[row]]];
```

It doesn't simply work at all. It keeps on asking to add the identifier error.

Same goes for this method, where the following works fine

```
    self.moods = @[@"I" , @"Love", @"Stack", @"Overflow", @"Great!"];
```

BUT the following code style doesn't work too

```
    [self moods] = @[@"I" , @"Love", @"Stack", @"Overflow", @"Great!"];
```

or even the setValue forKey ones in my case.

Alright, I agree that I'm fairly new to this and trying to self learn. I tried learning Objective-C and doing my best at it last week and covered all those concepts there. But it's my second day in iOS programming and am finding this minor stuff difficult to grasp.

Can you please help and guide a bit in detail? While following a bit of Stanford University classes video on iOS, they recommend to always use dot notation for properties. But you can use both, right? So I need to understand and build solid foundation. Thanks!

Comment: Curious, I've learned the setter and getter plus the indexing technique as shared. A lot of thanks for that, again. I've sent you an email as well Hossam, please check.

With that, I am finding this hard to write in bracket style. I seem to like bracket style more easy now.
the dot style is working
    cell.textLabel.text = justCourseNames[indexPath.row];
but this isn't why?
    [[cell textLabel] setText:justCourseNames[indexPath][row]];

Comment: By the way, that was about creating a table view and propagating it with plist data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id x = self.moods` => getter and its equal to `id x = [self moods]`

`self.moods = array` => setter and its equal to `[self setMoods:newArray]`

to access items:
`self.moods[index]`  OR `[self moods][index]`

Comment: Now that's Genius! Thank you so much.

Comment: Mistake here
let x:AnyObject = self.moods => getter and its equal to id x = [self moods]

Comment: The questions is on Objective-C not Swift :)